# How to disable my touch screen

Tags: linux, debian, drivers, cursor, touch-screen

My screen is cracked, and the touchscreen makes the courser spasm every once and a while. Is there any way i can fully disable it?

As requested:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    13023  2 
ccm                    17587  2 
rfcomm                 57995  0 
bnep                   17432  2 
bluetooth             386513  10 bnep,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           16588  1 bluetooth
binfmt_misc            16917  1 
loop                   26525  0 
rtsx_usb_ms            16899  0 
memstick               13654  1 rtsx_usb_ms
uvcvideo               78997  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      12816  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       12519  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         47704  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            12995  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              130540  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  18305  2 uvcvideo,videodev
hid_multitouch         17057  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45134  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    62994  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    63154  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
joydev                 17063  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    12951  0 
intel_powerclamp       17122  0 
intel_rapl             17344  0 
snd_hda_intel          26327  3 
mei_me                 17893  0 
snd_hda_controller     26631  1 snd_hda_intel
coretemp               12820  0 
arc4                   12501  2 
mei                    74977  1 mei_me
snd_hda_codec         108219  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
rtl8188ee              82986  0 
i915                  865455  3 
rtl_pci                25944  1 rtl8188ee
kvm_intel             138825  0 
rtlwifi                54679  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
mac80211              502208  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8188ee
cfg80211              438375  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
snd_hwdep              17205  1 snd_hda_codec
psmouse                98914  0 
snd_pcm                88538  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
serio_raw              12849  0 
pcspkr                 12595  0 
toshiba_acpi           27036  0 
sparse_keymap          12760  1 toshiba_acpi
rfkill                 18860  6 cfg80211,toshiba_acpi,bluetooth
kvm                   404853  1 kvm_intel
drm_kms_helper         49151  1 i915
drm                   253663  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
toshiba_bluetooth      12641  0 
crct10dif_pclmul       13348  0 
iTCO_wdt               12831  0 
iTCO_vendor_support    12649  1 iTCO_wdt
i2c_algo_bit           12751  1 i915
lpc_ich                20768  0 
i2c_i801               16964  0 
crc32_pclmul           12915  0 
i2c_core               50108  7 drm,i915,i2c_i801,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,v4l2_common,videodev
ghash_clmulni_intel    12978  0 
evdev                  17445  17 
video                  17991  1 i915
wmi                    17339  1 toshiba_acpi
cryptd                 18613  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_seq                57061  0 
snd_seq_device         13132  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              26768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    69285  16 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              13026  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
ac                     12715  0 
battery                13356  0 
processor              28159  0 
button                 12944  1 i915
ext4                  489947  1 
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                17171  1 ext4
jbd2                   82399  1 ext4
sg                     29973  0 
sd_mod                 44302  3 
crc_t10dif             12431  1 sd_mod
crct10dif_common       12356  2 crct10dif_pclmul,crc_t10dif
sr_mod                 21903  0 
cdrom                  51680  1 sr_mod
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         21184  0 
mmc_core              106257  1 rtsx_usb_sdmmc
rtsx_usb               17487  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
mfd_core               12601  2 lpc_ich,rtsx_usb
hid_generic            12393  0 
usbhid                 48607  0 
hid                   102250  3 hid_multitouch,hid_generic,usbhid
ata_generic            12490  0 
thermal                17559  0 
crc32c_intel           21809  0 
xhci_hcd              152894  0 
ehci_pci               12512  0 
ehci_hcd               69635  1 ehci_pci
ata_piix               33638  2 
alx                    36121  0 
mdio                   12599  1 alx
fan                    12681  0 
thermal_sys            27546  6 fan,video,intel_powerclamp,thermal,processor,x86_pkg_temp_thermal
usbcore               199395  6 uvcvideo,rtsx_usb,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid,xhci_hcd
usb_common             12440  1 usbcore
libata                181416  2 ata_generic,ata_piix
scsi_mod              195196  4 sg,libata,sd_mod,sr_mod
```

Comment: Presumably there is a module you could unload (and then blacklist)...

Comment: @jasonwryan How would one do that?

Comment: post the output of `lsmod`. There are wayyy too many to possible think of.

Comment: @SailorCire i did it

Comment: please verify the answer before rebooting. You could really do yourself in otherwise.

Comment: @SailorCire It worked thats why i did it...

Comment: Thank you. It just seemed like it went from submitted to accepted in 0.01 seconds. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `hid_multitouch` *might* be your driver.

***Before blacklisting, try the following:***

`modprobe -r hid_multitouch`

If this works then add it to the [blacklist](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/avoid-linux-kernel-module-driver-autoloading.html)

Comment: on a dell xps15 that also kills the touchpad :'-(

Comment: This one partially breaks my touchpad, as well as touchscreen isn't disabled. If anyone did it by accident, it can be fixed by `modprobe hid_multitouch`.

Answer (score 7):

1. find you touchscreen id:

> $xinput list

2. list it's properties

> $xinput list-props id

3. disable it by it's Name (as id's change with hid devices being plugged in & out), property & setting

> $xinput 'ATLM1000:00 03EB:8C0D Touchscreen' 153 0

4. you can add it to "startup applications" tool (in fluxbox ~/.fluxbox/startup), in this way you don't need to run it each power on. (In case of the ATLM touchscreen on next power on xinput list will not show the 'Touchscreen' thou the ATLM1000 will show.)

Comment: There's also a --disable flag which is pretty convenient.

Comment: It becomes `xinput disable 'ELAN2514:00 04F3:23DD'` in my case. It's a subset of "Virtual core pointer". There is a counterpart 'ELAN2514:00 04F3:23DD stylus' in "Virtual core keyboard", where disabling the latter doesn't work.